# How can I stream recorded video from an IP camera?

Tags: webcam, video-streaming, ip-camera

I'd like to record a certain area of my house while I'm away from home.

I downloaded [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam&hl=en) to turn my phone into an IP camera. I can then open up VLC on my computer and get a video stream from my phone's camera.

I'd like to be able to review recordings over the internet.

I'm thinking I could have VLC (or another app) record to a file on an ftp server so I can view it anywhere.

I don't know whether it's possible for one program to be recording to a file while the ftp server is reading that file, so it would help if the recording program saved the video in several video files, each 30 minutes long for example.

Comment: hi,if you can put your PC on and if you dont need to recive live stream then you can use your PC as Server for  example by using wamp server and then you can config your gateway for connecting over internet.if you want doing this way let me know to tell you with more details

Comment: I can do that, but I want to record the video, since I'm not going to be constantly looking at the stream. I want to view the already recorded video through the internet.

Comment: then you can use programmes that just recording the desktop with audio ;) and access the files from network as you  know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. There is an app called [vitamin d](http://vitamindinc.com/) which watches for any movement on a camera, then records it. You can then view the recorded clips. I can also share the phone over the internet to get a live view. If you have another solution, please answer anyway, it may end up being better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good article on [Webcam security systems](http://www.techradar.com/news/computing/how-to-set-up-a-webcam-security-system-1112863) here.

The first thing needed is [iSpy](http://www.ispyconnect.com/) and they have a very active community.  I have been testing recently and the motion activation works well.  I have a USB camera and an IP camera and both were easy to configure

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I needed the app to work for both Windows and Mac, but iSpy does look good.